# MYSQL DB write call gives error as "ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query" where as read call works fine

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection

Facing problem while making a write call to db, read call works fine.

```
InnoDB: Error: trying to access page number 825717632 in space 0,
InnoDB: space name ./ibdata1,
InnoDB: which is outside the tablespace bounds.
InnoDB: Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type 10.
InnoDB: If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that
InnoDB: your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the
InnoDB: MySQL server.
150622 15:02:55  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140009297241856 in file fil/fil0fil.c line 4135
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
20:02:55 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8384512
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=151
thread_count=1
connection_count=1
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 338336 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x282a9c0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f56746d5d98 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/libexec/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x29) [0x850989]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x483) [0x6a3ef3]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x342380f710]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x3423032625]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175) [0x3423033e05]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(fil_io+0x36e) [0x767e2e]
/usr/libexec/mysqld() [0x74fa03]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(buf_read_page+0x225) [0x750445]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(buf_page_get_gen+0x393) [0x749923]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(flst_insert_before+0x256) [0x772056]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(trx_purge_add_update_undo_to_history+0xf7) [0x7ccbe7]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(trx_undo_update_cleanup+0x29) [0x7dc789]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(trx_commit_off_kernel+0x1d9) [0x7db179]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(trx_commit_for_mysql+0x77) [0x7dbdd7]
/usr/libexec/mysqld() [0x72fd8a]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(ha_commit_one_phase(THD*, bool)+0x76) [0x697f06]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(ha_commit_trans(THD*, bool)+0x116) [0x6989c6]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(ha_autocommit_or_rollback(THD*, int)+0x28) [0x698cc8]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(dispatch_command(enum_server_command, THD*, char*, unsigned int)+0x191) [0x5d0ad1]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(do_command(THD*)+0xea) [0x5d220a]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x23e) [0x5c548e]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x34238079d1]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x34230e88fd]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7f565c004a00): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 1
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
150622 15:02:55 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
150622 15:02:55 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
150622 15:02:55  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
150622 15:02:55  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
150622 15:02:55  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 1 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is 0 143872
InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
InnoDB: Cleaning up trx with id 3120678387 2089
150622 15:02:55  InnoDB: Rollback of non-prepared transactions completed
150622 15:02:55  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 33747176
150622 15:02:55 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
150622 15:02:55 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

Comment: Your database file is very likely corrupted (or you've hit bug in MySQL itself)

Comment: Thanks Marki555, what could be resolution here ?

Comment: Best solution - wipe the datafiles and restore from backup (if you have it)... there are some tools to recover the data, but their usage is not easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer which worked for me. I had backup of data. I truncated all the tables and reinserted from backup.